# Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric while updateing decimal column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to update a decimal column (18,2):

```
update Product set Price = CAST(4675.00 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) where Id = 25465
```

I am getting the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Provide us with a [mre]. That query, on its own, won't replicate that error. *Also, why `CAST` the value `4657.00` to a `decimal(18.2)`? It's already a `decimal(6,2)` so casting it seems pointless. This feels like we are missing a lot of the full picture.*

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two reasons why this would occur.

The most obvious is that the table has an `update` trigger causing the problem.

The second is that `id` is really a character, and the `where` clause should be:

```
where Id = '25465'
```

Comment: The error is *"Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric."*, the `WHERE` in the question isn't the problem, as it would be converting a `int` to an `(n)varchar`. If that were the problem, then the error would be a truncation error, not a conversion error. a poorly written trigger is more likely the problem, as your initial thought suggests

Comment: @Larnu . . . The conversion goes in the other direction -- to a number not to a string:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7790fc85b252a7b99ffb171b1e8f90eb.

Comment: Apart from `23456` is not  `numeric` Gordon, as your db fiddle shows as the error differs. If you make the value a `numeric`, yes ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9d8b1f929e051d9db991c6e7c90f2f87)), but `23456` is an `int`, and this produces different errors.

Comment: @Larnu . . . The actual data type depends on the number of digits (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fbd9dca82428d4af69bc1e38ded2abcd).  The more important point is that a *string* is converted to a *number*, not vice versa.

Comment: My point, however, is unchanged, the above `WHERE` us *not* cause that error.